# MySQL 8: Alter definer of stored procedure

Tags: mysql

In versions of MySQL prior to 8, altering the definer of a stored procedure is possible by manipulating the `mysql.proc` table. This table was removed in 8 and replaced by the data dictionary. It looks like the definer can be modified using [`ALTER PROCEDURE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-procedure.html), but for the life of me I cannot get the syntax specified to work.

```
mysql> alter procedure refresh_basic sql security definer=`foo`@`127.0.0.1`;                                                                                                                
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=`foo`@`127.0.0.1`' at line 1
```

```
mysql> alter procedure refresh_basic sql security definer='foo@127.0.0.1';                                                                                                                  
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '='foo@127.0.0.1'' at line 1
```

I also tried both of the above without using `=`, but got similar errors. How does one actually do this? Thanks!

Comment: Because definer  is a [MySQL user account](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/account-names.html) it needs to be in the format `'user'@'host'` format.so it needs to be `definer='foo'@'127.0.0.1'`.. This seams to be a *"problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error"* type of question so most likely this question will be voteclosed.

Comment: The documentation that you linked to says ``Quote user names and host names as identifiers or as strings, using either backticks (`), single quotation marks ('), or double quotation marks (").`` Using backticks is what I did in my first code snippet.

Comment: You can only change the security context between the `DEFINER` and the `INVOKER` with the `alter procedure`-command, not change the definer itself. Looks like you have to recreate the procedure to set the correct definer. The definer is stored in mysql.routines tables which are not directly accessible.